# a function in lisp called xtoy which returns a list from x to y

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, practical-common-lisp, ansi-common-lisp

I am very new to lisp. I am trying to write a function named x2y which takes 2 arguments x and y which are integers and return a list of integers which starts from x and ends at y

```
(defun xtoy (X Y)
  (cond ((> X Y) (list nil))
        ((= X Y) (list Y)))
        (T (append (list X) x2y(+ 1 X) Y)))))
```

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: the code was not working which i pasted along with the question but its solved now

Comment: @shunya: Please not that elisp and common-lisp are **different** languages which both are in the lisp family. If you are going to ask a question please tag with the language the problem is in.

Comment: @Baggers sorry i just started learning lisp i was not aware that elisp is a different language than common lisp. i removed the tag of elisp now

Comment: @shunya: No worries! reading my comment again now it seems a bit stern so sorry about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting with abo-abo's version, you can simplify a lot:

1) get rid of (= X Y) and replace (list nil) by nil in (> X Y)

```
(defun xtoy (X Y)
  (cond ((> X Y) nil)
        (t (append (list X) (xtoy (+ 1 X) Y)))))
```

2) simplify `cond` to an `if`statement

```
(defun xtoy (X Y)
  (if (<= X Y)
    (append (list X) (xtoy (+ 1 X) Y))
    nil))
```

3) leave out the final `nil`, because that's what's implicitly returned when the condition doesn't match

```
(defun xtoy (X Y)
  (if (<= X Y)
    (append (list X) (xtoy (+ 1 X) Y))))
```

4) use `cons` instead of `append`

```
(defun xtoy (X Y)
  (if (<= X Y)
    (cons X (xtoy (+ 1 X) Y))))
```

Comment: Ah I see there is an elisp and common lisp tags on this question, blimey

Answer (score 3):

In elisp, you're looking for <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>f</kbd> `number-sequence` <kbd>RET</kbd>.

Answer (score 2):

The code that you give in your question is in a very messy state.
Emacs can highlight parens for you.
That was enough for me to fix your code without any debugging:

```
(defun xtoy (X Y)
  (cond ((> X Y) (list nil))
        ((= X Y) (list Y))
        (t (append (list X) (xtoy (+ 1 X) Y)))))
```

This is how you turn on highlighting:

```
(setq show-paren-mode t)
```

Do most of your editing in `*scratch*` or `ielm` - they make things easier.

Comment: No, the OP just had a confusion about the invocation syntax, which is `(xtoy (1+ x))` and not `x2y(1+ x)`. I see this confusion extraordinarily frequently in the questions I see here on SO.

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young, there's still two extra closing parens in the question code.

Answer (score 1):

If you need help with your function I suggest you use `cons` instead of `list` and make it from end to start with an accumulator.

```
(defun xtoy (from to &optional acc)
  (if (> from to)
      acc
      (xtoy from (- to 1) (cons to acc))))
```